# Mongoose RESTful HTTP Server

Tags: c++, c, http, mongoose

I'm working on a mongoose http server. It's very simple and easy. The 'primary' process of the http event all happened inside the event handler. But I don't want to keep all those code inside a same process (for some reason).

Is there any suggestions to achieve below:

1. Received event from mongoose inside event handler. Extract the JSON and insert into an 'in queue' (linked list). Job done here. (I know how to do this)
2. Another thread pop the in queue and proceed the JSON. Format the response packet and insert into another 'out queue'. (I know how to do this)
3. Another thread pop the out queue and use the 'stored connection info' to send the response packet back to requestor. (This is where I'm stuck)

The concern is how to get the client connection handle out from the event handler?

If timeout or remote party cancel the request, i believe the connection will become invalid (remove by mongoose library or so), how to handle this?

Comment: Are you constraint to use mangoose? Because there are couple of other c++ libs you can use to do this trick easily.

Comment: Hi Kola... not necessary to be Mongoose. I just try around with it. But anywhere, i found another method from Boost.Asio + Boost.Beast  :)

Comment: yes, Boost::Beast  was one of the options I meant, the other one is [RESTinio](https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio) which allows a less boilerplate compared to use of Boost::Beast.